# Apache Crunch: How to set multiple input paths?

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2, apache-crunch

I have a problem: I can't set the multiple input paths when I use the Apache Crunch. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the multiple input files to crunch by specifying all the input paths in a List.

```
public class Name {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pipeline pipeline =  new MRPipeline(Name.class, jobName, conf);
    List<Path> inputPathList = new ArrayList<>(); // Add your InputPaths here
    PCollection<String> source = From.sequenceFile(inputPathList, Text.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: You may have solved this but this definitely helps a newbie in the crunch who is searching for the same question.